# The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I am getting this error when i am trying to call reports from application. My reports is working properly on report server.

I am using below code:

```
Private Sub ShowJobTravelerReport(ByVal strworkORdeID As String, ByVal strQAFormID As String, ByVal strReportName As String)
        Dim paramList As New Generic.List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter)
        paramList.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("WorkOrderID", strworkORdeID, False))
        paramList.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("QAFormID", strQAFormID, False))
        showReport(strReportName, paramList)
    End Sub


Private Sub showReport(ByVal strReportName As String, ByRef paramList As Generic.List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter))
    Try
        ' Load data only when displaying the page for the first time
        If (Not Me.IsPostBack) Then
            Dim newuri As New Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyReportViewerUrl").ToString())
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyReportViewerReportPath").ToString() + strReportName.trim()
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = newuri
            ' Dim rptcon As 
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New MyReportServerCredentials()
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList)
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        ' An error has occured so display an error message.
        Utils.RegisterJScriptAlert(Me, "Page_Load_Error_Message", ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

My Web.Config file is below..

```
<add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="MyReportServerConnection, App_Code" />
<add key="MyReportViewerReportPath" value="/Reports/" />
<add key="MyReportViewerUrl" value="http://MyServer:port/Reports" />
<add key="MyReportViewerDomain" value="*******" />
<add key="MyReportViewerPassword" value="******" />
<add key="MyReportViewerUser" value="******" />
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you what is wrong, right in the error - *Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version*. So there is likely to be some difference between development and production in one of these areas... You could verify that you can actually connect manually, using the exact credentials - perhaps something (like a firewall) is interfering with your connection, or maybe there is a typo in the credentials. If this isn't the case, maybe try comparing software versions, trying to find and resolve any discrepancies. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responce but i have tried to connect report server directly using exact credentiala and its working fine. When i try through application it shows this error.

Comment: Right on... what about the software versions?

Answer (score 0):

For me this has nothing to do with version.

In SSRS 2014 I solved this by modifying my rsreportserver.config file.  My ReportServerUrl setting was wrong.  I changed it to my actual SSRS ReportServer URL.

Like this:

```
<ReportServerUrl>http://localhost/InstanceName_ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
```

I got help from [this page](http://stepbistep.net/2012/02/28/ssrs-error-2-the-attempt-to-connect-to-the-report-server-failed-check-your-connection-information-and-that-the-report-server-is-a-compatible-version/), which had instructions for a previous version of SSRS.